# NAA flag declined: flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70137212/find-frequency-of-consecutive-digits-n-times/70137279#70137279) tagged `java` `arrays` `string`:

> #### Find frequency of consecutive digits N times
>
> Given a string of digits and a number n
> String = 500055 n = 2
> then output -> 510352
> explanation: here I'm counting the frequency of consecutive digits and storing them.

The following ["answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70137279/13279831) contains a couple of JavaScript and HTML snippets showing how to implement a **countdown timer**.  It could be presumable posted because some keyword `count` could match.

> you can use this code javascript countdown 10 seconds:
> .. JavaScript snippet
> countdown in javascript :
> .. HTML + JS snippet

It is crystal clear that the mentioned answer is blatantly off-topic and *it does not attempt to answer the question.* therefore *It should possibly be ... deleted altogether*.

There's an upvoted comment mentioning that the answer is unrelated to the OP's question.

So my question is simple: which tool should be used to flag and clear out such off-topic answers if NAA / calling to moderator's attention are not an option?   Downvoting the answer is pretty useless -- the answerer has a rep of 1.  Did I have to flag it as a Low Quality answer?  That could also result in a declined flag.

Comment: A read of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer should be instructive.

Comment: *"Downvoting the answer is pretty useless -- the answerer has a rep of 1."* - the reason you should downvote is to signal to other users that the answer is bad - you should not downvote simply because you think a user should have less reputation.

Comment: Additionally 20K users can delete answers with a negative score so you're helping them and when you get to 20K you can join in too.

Comment: @RobertLongson, a good illustration -- here's an orange instead of an apple

Comment: @AlexRudenko except... it's an Apple, not an Orange. it's 100% an answer, to some question, somewhere, wherever the answer was copied from. it's simply a wrong answer.

Comment: Very Low Quality is also reviewed by moderators, @kaya3. The only difference between VLQ and NAA is that the former is invalidated automatically by an edit.

Comment: Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610682/git-list-of-staged-files/65785881#65785881) (with +10/-2. Two (not deleted) answers total).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, at least this answer was about `git` and not `CVS` :)

Comment: "Downvoting the answer is pretty useless -- the answerer has a rep of 1" - ai ai ai, you downvote to punish. Not cool.

Comment: Not quite, @Gimby although I try to avoid downvoting as much as possible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct tool to use to get rid of such answers is a delete vote. Once you reach 20k reputation points you can vote to delete such answers.

You could try to raise a custom moderator flag explaining why you think such answer needs to be deleted, but be warned that moderators' job isn't to judge content. This is why we have downvotes and delete votes. Moderators are usually helpful in eliminating similar problems, so you might be lucky.

You could also visit [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where you can find people with 20k+ who would be happy to evaluate it and cast their delete votes.

Do not use NAA/VLQ flags to handle content like this as they are NOT designed to handle such issues. These flags are reserved for content that is not an answer at all.

Most importantly, **you should downvote answers like this.** This is exactly why we have downvotes. Regardless of how much reputation the author has, your job is to rate the usefulness of content, and an answer suggesting a JavaScript solution to the Java question is definitely useless.

Comment: I tried custom moderator flag -- it was also declined.  Ok, I think I clarified this issue for myself.